# why is my code returning nil in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am trying to calculate freezing point of 0 Fahrenheit. My code is returning nil. I am trying to solve a question in http://testfirst.org/ . So I created a Temperature class. created a Hash. I iterate over each hash. With the value I iterate and do the calculation

My Code

```
class Temperature
  attr_accessor :f

  def initialize(f)
    f = Hash.new
    @f = f
  end 

  def to_fahrenheit
    50  
  end

  def to_celsius
    f.each do |key, value| 
      @to_c = if value == 32
                0
              elsif value == 212
                100
              elsif value == 98.6
                37 
              elsif value == 68
                20
              else
                f = value.to_f
                (f -32 ) / 1.8  
              end
    end
    @to_c
  end
end
```

My Test

```
require "temperature"

describe Temperature do

  describe "can be constructed with an options hash" do
    describe "in degrees fahrenheit" do
      it "at 50 degrees" do
      end

      describe "and correctly convert to celsius" do
        it "at freezing" do
          Temperature.new({:f => 32}).to_celsius.should == 0
        end

        it "at boiling" do
          Temperature.new({:f => 212}).to_celsius.should == 100
        end

        it "at body temperature" do
          Temperature.new({:f => 98.6}).to_celsius.should == 37
        end

        it "at an arbitrary temperature" do
          Temperature.new({:f => 68}).to_celsius.should == 20
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My terminal

```
 1) Temperature can be constructed with an options hash in degrees fahrenheit and correctly convert to celsius at freezing
     Failure/Error: Temperature.new({:f => 32}).to_celsius.should == 0
       expected: 0
            got: nil (using ==)
     # ./10_temperature_object/temperature_object_spec.rb:31:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: For things like this you should really be storing in °C or °K as those are used in a scientific context. °F is an anachronism used mostly by Americans and few others.

Comment: It's also curious that you've got so many special cases in here when the °F -> °C conversion is a simple linear equation: "°C = (°F  -  32) *  (5/9)" Also note your test coverage is really thin, you should be testing at least a dozen random points to ensure you get the right values.

Comment: This is just loaded with confusion. `Temperature.new(f: 20).to_fahrenheit` returns `50`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your initialize method, you're overwriting the hash that is passed into the function.

```
   def initialize(f)
        f = Hash.new
        @f = f
    end
```

should be something like

```
   def initialize(f={})
        @f = f
    end
```

Comment: You are right.. :) I actually looking for where OP missed `@f`.. That's the place I found.. And by mistake gave a bad answer.. but you should have your *+1*..

Answer (score 1):

You've reused the variable `f` a lot in your code and I think that is causing your problem.

You're naming the variable that is passed into your constructor `f`, then assigning a new, empty, hash to it. This sets your local `attr_accessor :f` or `@f` to a new hash.

Then you're reassigning your local `f` in the block that does the calculations with `f = value.to_f` whilst you're actually looping through `f`.

You need to address the constructor reassignment and then use a different local variable name for your `value.to_f` conversion.

Comment: "This sets your local attr_accessor :f or @f to a new hash." No, `f = Hash.new` does not call the `f=` accessor function. It creates a local variable called `f`. To call the accessor function, he'd need to call `self.f = Hash.new`. However on the next line where he does `@f = f`, he does set `@f` to the empty hash.